# Установка объекта класса как источник разметки

Tags: java, android

Пожалуйста, помогите. Как установить объект класса `Picture`

```
public class Picture extends View{
public Picture (Context c) { super(c); }
/*...*/
}
```

в качестве источника разметки Activity:

```
setContentView();
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setContentView(new Picture(YourActivity.this));
```